Inconsistent jump height when rotating character left or right
I am developing an endless runner mobile game, Similar to Subway Surfers. I make my player character rotate slightly left or right and then return to facing forward when sliding left or right. The issue is that this rotation makes the character's jump inconsistent, resulting in different jump heights.
How can I make the jump consistent? Below are the scripts I am using.
In the PlayerController script:
public void SetVelocity(Vector3 velocity)
{
    CController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    //Rotate the player a bit where is going
    Vector3 dir = CController.velocity;
    if (dir != Vector3.zero)
    {
        dir.y = 0;
        transform.forward = Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, dir, data.RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

In PlayerJumping script:
public override void Enter()
{
    player.velocityY = data.jumpForce;
}

private void UpdateJumpMovement()
{
    // Aplly gravity
    player.velocityY += data.gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;

    pos.x = player.SnapToLane();
    pos.y = player.velocityY;
    pos.z = player.currentSpeed;

    player.SetVelocity(pos);
}


A few minor notes on code clarity: here you're assigning jumpForce directly to velocityY, not applying it as a force. So I'd recommend naming that variable jumpSpeed instead, to communicate it's a speed measured in metres per second, not a force measured in Newtons. Similarly, pos is being passed into SetVelocity(), so it's really a velocity or vel, not a "position" as its current naming implies. Renaming the variables won't solve this problem, but it makes the code easier to reason about and makes it less tempting to introduce errors down the line with false assumptions.

What exactly is the CController in the first script? Is that a reference to the standard CharacterController provided by Unity or something else?

It is the standard character controller provided by Unity.

You haven't provided enough context for us to tell what is wrong. For example, what is the data structure with fields jumpForce and gravity? What is the component that player references?
